# What's the best way to refactor a large switch statement in java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a gross switch statement that I need to figure out how to refine. I immediately think factory pattern, but I don't know if I want to actually use objects for these purposes. How could you reduce the verbosity of this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were to, I would

- Define a `Validator` interface
- Implement this interface for length, width, angle.
- Define a map of `<Integer, Validator interface>` with key as index and value as the corresponding `Validator` implementation
- In the for loop, based on the index, get the appropriate `Validator` implementation and run it.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Viktor has the preferred solution but if all you are trying to do is reduce the code, but keep the structure you could.

change

```
if (isValidBorrowAmount(amount) == false) {
    isValidValue = false;
    print("That value does not work here");
}
```

to

```
isValidValue = isValidBorrowAmount(amount);
```

and after the switch block put

```
if(!isValidValue){
    print("That value does not work here");
}
```